# Combobox 'box_value'

Tags: python, combobox

I'd like to put a combobox in my program and when I do something like this:

```
from Tkinter import Tk, StringVar
from ttk import Label, Combobox,Frame,Button

class App(Frame):

    def __init__(self,root):
        Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.root = root
        self.combo()
        self.initUI()

    def combo(self):
        self.box_value=StringVar()
        self.box = Combobox(self, textvariable = self.box_value,state = 'readonly')
        self.box['values'] = ('a','b')
        self.box.current(0)
        self.box.grid(row=0,column =0)
    def initUI(self):
        self.lab = Label(self,text = '')
        self.lab.grid(row=1,column=0)
        self.but = Button(self,text ='OK',command = self.cho)
        self.but.grid(row=2,column=0)
    def cho(self):    
        x = self.box.get()
        self.lab.config(text = x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   root = Tk()
   App(root).pack()
   root.mainloop()
```

It works properly. But when I put it into my another program It gives me an error that:     " Program instance has no attribute 'box_vaule' "
Here is part of code:

```
class Program(Frame):

        def __init__(self, root):

            Frame.__init__(self, root)
            self.root = root       
            self.initUI()
            self.combo()

        def initUI(self):

            self.root.title('Emission')
            self.root.configure(background ='#6666ff')
            Style().configure('TFrame', background = '#6666ff')
            Style().configure('TButton',background = '#6666ff')
            grid all stuff....

        def combo(self):
            self.box_value = StringVar()
            self.box = Combobox(self,textvariable = self.box_vaule,state = 'readonly')
            self.box['values'] = ('a','b','c')
            self.box.current(0)
            self.box.grid(row=24,columnspan=6)
if __name__=='__main__':
    root = Tk()
    Program(root).pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

I can not find any bugs in this code. Can anyone help me? Full error message is like this:
"   self.box = Combobox(self,textvariable = self.box_vaule,state = 'readonly')
AttributeError: Program instance has no attribute 'box_vaule'"

Comment: That's just a typo. Change `box_vaule` to `box_value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have made a typo typing 'vaule' instead of 'value'

Change

```
self.box_value = StringVar()
self.box = Combobox(self,textvariable = self.box_vaule,state = 'readonly')
```

to

```
self.box_value = StringVar()
self.box = Combobox(self, textvariable=self.box_value, state='readonly')
```

Note how I also added and removed some spaces here and there to match the Python style better.

Comment: How could I be so blind :) Thank You very much :)